# error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 182: did not find expected '-' indicator in calico yaml

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, calico

I am setting up Kubernetes cluster network configuration through calico and while performing
'kubectl apply -f calico.yaml', I get the following error

error: error parsing calico.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 182: did not find expected '-' indicator

I am using default yaml file as specified in https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml

Have anyone come across this and resolved. Any other suggestions please.

Comment: Why don't try directly `kubectl apply -f https://.../calico.yaml`

Comment: Simple, make sure your edited values are properly aligned since it is yaml format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply this yaml with no need to save it locally. As peterzinho16 said just run:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/manifests/calico.yaml
```

Then all resources will be created.